# Как найти переменную экземпляра класса?

Tags: php, ооп

В классе есть нужный мне метод. Непонятно объект уже создан или надо его мне создать. Проверяю:

```
$class = class_exists('MyClass'); // bool(true)
```

Экземпляр уже есть, но как к нему обратиться? В какой он переменной что бы сделать:

```
$exemplar->method('мои данные');
```

Comment: `class_exists != instance_exists`

Comment: Так создайте экземпляр класса в переменную через new и работайте с ним

Comment: А он проверил класс, но это не значит что он был внедрён? (создан экземпляр), а как проверить объявление? get_declared_classes ?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko он может быть уже создан до меня, а я создам второй экземпляр

Comment: Ну уж извините, тут ничего не поделать. Его может быть уже штук 10... Вы на то и программист, чтоб понимать, создан уже или нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать поиск класса через перебор всех объявленных переменных получаемых от функции [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-defined-vars.php)

Набросок кода:

```
class classA{}
class classB{}
class classC extends classA{}

$aa = new classA;
$bb = new classB;
$cc = new classC;

foreach(get_defined_vars() as $v => $c) {
    if (is_a($c, 'classA') && get_class($c) === 'classA') {
        var_dump($v);
    }
}
```

Выведет:

```
string(2) "aa"
```

P.S. Описание функций is_a() и get_class() смотрите там же, в мануале.